# What can I do if my aircraft type changes last minute?

Tags: safety, commercial-aviation, boeing, commercial-operations

I have a flight scheduled for June with a popular, European commercial budget-operator on a 737. I'm sure everyone knows about the [groundings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737_MAX_groundings#Return_to_service) of the MAX. However, I'm concerned that the MAX may be returning to service around the time I'm scheduled to fly.

I absolutely would not fly on one of these types, yes Boeing have completed 96 test flights and yes, they guarantee a thorough 'safety update' to the software.. but it's too little, too late for me.

***Can I get a refund/alternative flight if my aircraft type changes last minute?***

I know initially it seems this might be better suited on the travel SE, but I don't think people there will know much about specific type grou*ndings, and even if they did, it's unlikely they will have access to information required to answer this question. Basically, I was hoping someone working in the commercial space would have an answer, and most of those people are on this site.*

Comment: This is a question about the *Passenger side* of aviation - which is better suited to Travel.se

Comment: @Jamiec I did consider that, I will update the question to include my reasoning for posting it here. Please remove your downvote.

Comment: Cloud, this question is about your transportation agreement with the airline, their  general terms and conditions, and any other legal obligations they might have. It is not about aviation (as defined for this SE).

Comment: I don't see how the update makes it suited for this SE instead of [travel.se]

Answer (score 5):

Nothing besides cancelling or rebooking (while hoping the new flight will have a different type assigned to it).

Unless your transport contract with the airline goes into inordinate detail about the service to be rendered you won't be able to dictate what type of aircraft should the used for the trip.

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment of the OP. A close relative of mine intentionally books quads for transoceanic flights and would be very much not amused if a twin was subbed in. Still, nothing one can do - airline‘s choice. Aircraft type is generally not a guaranteed booking option.

Comment: I guess he´s not a fan of ETOPS: Engines Turn or Passengers Swim :)

Comment: Exactly. I pointed out that the risk of experiencing an engine failure increases with number of engines, but they still insisted they didn’t like the prospect of flying three hours on one engine over stormy water of four degrees...

Comment: @CptReynolds Thanks Cpt. Although, I feel my worry is a bit more grounded... the MAX (and the NEOs for that matter) have proven themselves unsafe on multiple occasions recently. Obviously this is not the case for general twin types.